Is the intersection of an analytic subset with a closed subset an analytic subset?

Let  $X$ be an irreducible complex space (one may assume it is a complex manifold,
as you like) and $A\subseteq X$ an irreducible  analytic set of $X$ satisfying $A\neq X$, and $C$ a
closed subset of $X$.
My question: is $A\cap C$  an analytic set of $X$?

The following are several common equivalent definitions of analytic sets：
a) An analytic set in a complex  space $X$ are a closed sets in $X$ which locally is the zero sets of finitely generated  (=coherent)  ideals.
b) Equivalently,  a subset $A$ of a complex space $X$ is called analytic, if there is a coherent ideal $I \subset O_X$ such that
$$
A=\operatorname{supp}\left(O_X / I\right).
$$
c)
Equivalently,  a closed subset $A$ of $X$ is said to be analytic if for every point $x \in A$ there exists an open neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ in $X$ such that there are finitely many holomorphic functions $g_1, \ldots, g_l$ on $V_x$ with
$$
V_x \cap A=\left\{y \in V_x ; g_1(y)=\cdots=g_l(y)=0\right\} .
$$

Did you try the case of $X=A=\mathbb C$? What did you conclude?

@MoisheKohan  Thank you. I have reedited the post, and assume that $A$ is a proper analytic set of $X$.

OK, then take $X=\mathbb C^2$ and $A$ a complex line in $X$. What can you say in this case?

@MoisheKohan  Great, since $\mathbb{C}^2$ is Stein, we only need to take a bounded $C$ to produce a counterexample.
